# ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 - adding custom key metadata to raster dataset

Tags: arcpy, metadata

I wonder if there's option to create custom key metadata to raster/image datasets. By default ArcMap gives few key metadata types:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/raster-dataset-properties.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_D03DC4400F7B4D48A128773A2C75709E

ArcPy gives function SetRasterKeyMetadata() which can only insert default metadata.